# Terraform init failed. Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure, hashicorp

Installed terraform & init is failing.

```
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 4.16"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": x509: “cf-registry.tf-registry-prod-use1.terraform.io” certificate is not standards compliant
```

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled it but still not working.
Terraform version: Terraform v1.3.7 on darwin_amd64

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, even with a module that was working well previously. After discarding network issues ( `curl https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json` ), trying with different files and directories, etc. It turned out that a reboot did the trick for me.